# How to disable local package dependency for `npm install --prefix`?

Tags: node.js, json, npm

I have a project with at its root the following simplified `package.json` file:

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "parent-project",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

In a subfolder that we'll call `child-project`, another `package.json` resides:

**child-project / package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "child-project",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
  }
}
```

[Some code that I depend on](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/src/schematics/deploy/actions.ts#L239) uses the command `npm --prefix ./child-project install` to install dependencies in `child-project`. However, this always has the undesirable side-effect of altering `child-project/package.json` like so:

```json
{
  "name": "child-project",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "parent-project": "file:.." // <- I don't want this!
  }
}
```

When I execute `cd ./child-project && npm install` all is fine and `child-project/package.json` remains untouched, so my hunch is that it has to do with `--prefix` but documentation on `--prefix` is very obscure.

Is there a way to disable this behaviour and prevent NPM from altering the `child-project/package.json`?

Comment: Which version of npm are you using? Which OS?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei  8.5.5 on windows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like there are some issues with the `--prefix`.

However, I couldn't find any issue while I was testing with different modules which have sub-packages.

Hence, [according](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/1368#issuecomment-1241076700) to one of the npm contributors, it is going to be refactored or removed in a future release, which means it is not the best choice to use it at least for now. So I recommend you go through the traditional way and avoid using `--prefix`.

> I think we're gonna close this as a wontfix as --prefix is not the best flag to be promoting. We do eventually want to refactor or remove it but for now we should at least not be promoting it.